# Get HTML Code of Website after selecting item in dropdown list

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, web

Our school has a site where you can look up if teachers are ill or if we have another teacher in a lesson (german: Vertretungsplan). So this site is made with a system called "Untis". But every time when I open the site in Safari on my iPhone, i had to log in. So I decided to make an app, which takes the content of this site and shows it in a `UITableView`. Now the problem: when I open the site it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is now that I need to select an item in the "dropbox" under "Element", before he shows the content. The HTML Code of the "dropbox" under "Element" is:

```
<select name="element" class="selectbox" onchange="doDisplayTimetable(NavBar, topDir);">
```

After this, all items of the "dropbox" are listed.
A before this select-tag is a form-tag looking like this:

```
<form name="NavBar" method="post">
```

So I thought now, if it is possible, that I load and login on the page with `NSURLRequest` or anything else and then send a `POST` to the website, which selects a item?

I really don't know anything about website-forms.
Here is a picture of a part of the HTML Code of the website:

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at running javascript on the loaded page if possible to either select the item or call the function being called in the selectbox

Comment: Here is some apple documentation on running javascript from Objc https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html

Comment: Thanks. I found the function in the javascript file and found out, how I can create a link, which will show me the "Vertretungsplan" directly. I opened the Timelines Tab in my Safari Element-Information and saw, that when I change the item, the browser opens a link, which contains a number. Now I only have to change that number to display an other item of the dropbox.
So for the first item, he calls .../w00000.htm and for the second he calls .../w00001.htm.

So Thank you, you solved my question :)